# authorize.net response_url https/http issue

Tags: php, http, https, authorize.net

Authorize.net consumes my response_url, which is on HTTP, into their HTTPS hosted dll.  How can I specify that their dll should be on HTTP, so that my CSS and JS files get pulled in correctly?

I don't have a way of getting access to an SSL host at the moment.

Edit:  First, we send from HTTP to their HTTPS hosted form.  On *their* server.  Then, their server consumes our HTTP page and dispalys it in their HTTPS response dll.

I only want their response_dll to be on HTTP.  I don't see a security issue with that, and imagine there is a way to do this, as their service offering is meant for people without SSL enabled.

Edit2: I'm using their Simple Checkout API.

Comment: You can't.  It's a really bad idea to send payment information over HTTP and a.net isn't likely to allow that.

Comment: i think the answer is no but which service of theirs are you using - simple checkout? DPM? also you should search and post here http://community.developer.authorize.net

Comment: @cartalot -- thanks. i'll edited again to specify simple checkout.

Comment: well… DPM might be a better option for you - they definitely state that you do not need SSL http://developer.authorize.net/api/dpm/ otherwise see if you can have it be their default payment page without your css etc.

Comment: @cartalot i'll check that out, but am going to leave the question open for awhile because I think it's an important question that I've seen around the web, and I think it deserves a stack seo boost

Comment: FYI if you are signed up with them you can contact authorize tech support directly.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, based on some advice to contact tech support directly.  I did, and their response was:

"We can only relay the html content. We do not offer to relay other content such as images. It is necessary that any images you want to include are hosted using https."

Edit --

I attempted to include a single logo image as a base64 string inside a static html page. That failed with a "script timeout".  I speculate this is due to the size of the html file after using that string.

This is a total failure on the part of Authorize.Net